# melt function from reshape2 package

Tags: r

I keep getting a message saying that "objects are masked from 'package:data.table': dcast, melt" "Error: id variables not found in data: b". I tried to use the :: method and hoping it would work but it's not. What are other solutions out there? Any inputs are appreciated! Thank you!

```
library(reshape2)
mdat <- reshape2::melt (data2, id = 'b')
head(mdat)
```

Comment: For what it’s worth the package is deprecated and replaced by ‘tidyr’, in particular `tidyr::pivot_longer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Define `idvar` instead of `id`:

```
#Code
reshape2::melt(iris,idvar='Species')
```

In your case:

```
#Code2
mdat <- reshape2::melt (data2, idvar = 'b')
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` as tidyr functions mostly supercede the `reshape2` package functions

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(data2 cols = -b)
```